# Fast inverse square of double in C/C++

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, square-root

Recently I was profiling a program in which the hotspot is definitely this

```
double d = somevalue();
double d2=d*d;
double c = 1.0/d2   // HOT SPOT
```

The value d2 is not used after because I only need value c. Some time ago I've read about the Carmack method of fast inverse square root, this is obviously not the case but I'm wondering if a similar algorithms can help me computing 1/x^2.

I need quite accurate precision, I've checked that my program doesn't give correct results with gcc -ffast-math option. (g++-4.5)

Comment: Wikipedia has [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Approximations_that_depend_on_IEEE_representation) for that. Frankly, I'd first nuke d2 (i.e. use `double c = 1.0/(d*d);`)and see if compiler can figure something out.

Comment: how about `pow(d,-2)`, or an identity such as `e^(ln(d)*(-1/2))`

Comment: also fast inverse square root - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: I don't need square root...I need a fast inverse of square.

Comment: Carmacks hack is long outperformed by SSE sets. Use library function and measure, if it's not gonna be good enough, take a look at gmp.
What level of precision do you need?
Ln can be easily rewritten into few iterations of taylor serie (with table of few precomputed variables, but you are hardly gonna match gmp code in speed nor precision).

Comment: @SigTerm: The compiler is already capable of doing that step for you, doing simple substitutions almost never has an impact on modern compilers.  (A modern compiler will typically translate both into the same IR, more or less.)

Comment: @scibuff: The `pow` function is going to be slower than division.  Actually, the **exact same** assembly code will be emitted for `1.0/(x*x)` and `pow(x, -2)` when GCC uses `-ffast-math`.

Comment: It's all very nice, but has *anyone* even noticed the question isn't about inverse square *roots*  but just about inverse *squares*?

Comment: What percent of time is in this hot spot? Put another way: how much would overall time decrease if that line took 0 time (like if you could comment it out)? I'm only asking because profilers often point the finger at little stuff and miss the big stuff.

Comment: The computation is inside a double nested for loop and it takes 50% of time. That double nested loops is the core of the program and it takes 80% of it (it's a pairwise potential field computation).

Comment: Not to persist, but how do you know that? If you answer `gprof` I would encourage you to try something else. A simple way is just comment out the suspicious line and see how much less time it uses. Then there has got to be indexing and other stuff going on. 50% is kind of an odd number. I would immediately be curious what the other 50% was. Loop overhead? Does unrolling make sense?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes, it's an hotspot in the profile

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The tricks for doing fast square roots and the like get their performance by sacrificing precision.  (Well, most of them.)

1. Are you sure you need `double` precision?  You can sacrifice precision easily enough:

   ```
   double d = somevalue();
   float c = 1.0f / ((float) d * (float) d);
   ```

   The `1.0f` is absolutely mandatory in this case, if you use `1.0` instead you will get `double` precision.
2. Have you tried enabling "sloppy" math on your compiler?  On GCC you can use `-ffast-math`, there are similar options for other compilers.  The sloppy math may be more than good enough for your application.  (**Edit:** I did not see any difference in the resulting assembly.)
3. If you are using GCC, have you considered using `-mrecip`?  There is a "reciprocal estimate" function which only has about 12 bits of precision, but it is much faster.  You can use the Newton-Raphson method to increase the precision of the result.  The `-mrecip` option will cause the compiler to automatically generate the reciprocal estimate and Newton-Raphson steps for you, although you can always write the assembly yourself if you want to fine tune the performance-precision trade-off.  (Newton-Raphson converges *very* quickly.) (**Edit:** I was unable to get GCC to generate RCPSS.  See below.)

I found a blog post ([source](http://www.pvk.ca/Blog/LowLevel/software-reciprocal.html)) discussing the exact problem you are going through, and the author's conclusion is that the techniques like the Carmack method are not competitive with the RCPSS instruction (which the `-mrecip` flag on GCC uses).

**The reason** why division can be so slow is because processors generally only have one division unit and it's often not pipelined.  So, you can have a few multiplications in the pipe all executing simultaneously, but no division can be issued until the previous division finishes.

### Tricks that don't work

1. Carmack's method: It is obsolete on modern processors, which have reciprocal estimation opcodes.  For reciprocals, the best version I've seen only gives one bit of precision -- nothing compared to the 12 bits of `RCPSS`.  I think it is a coincidence that the trick works so well for reciprocal square roots; a coincidence that is unlikely to be repeated.
2. Relabeling variables.  As far as the compiler is concerned, there is very little difference between `1.0/(x*x)` and `double x2 = x*x; 1.0/x2`.  I would be surprised if you found a compiler that generates different code for the two versions with optimizations turned on even to the lowest level.
3. Using `pow`.  The `pow` library function is a total monster.  With GCC's `-ffast-math` turned off, the library call is fairly expensive.  With GCC's `-ffast-math` turned on, you get the exact same assembly code for `pow(x, -2)` as you do for `1.0/(x*x)`, so there is no benefit.

### Update

Here is an example of a Newton-Raphson approximation for the inverse square of a double-precision floating-point value.

```
static double invsq(double x)
{
    double y;
    int i;
    __asm__ (
        "cvtpd2ps %1, %0\n\t"
        "rcpss %0, %0\n\t"
        "cvtps2pd %0, %0"
        : "=x"(y)
        : "x"(x));
    for (i = 0; i < RECIP_ITER; ++i)
        y *= 2 - x * y;
    return y * y;
}
```

Unfortunately, with `RECIP_ITER=1` benchmarks on my computer put it slightly slower (~5%) than the simple version `1.0/(x*x)`.  It's faster (2x as fast) with zero iterations, but then you only get 12 bits of precision.  I don't know if 12 bits is enough for you.

I think one of the problems here is that this is too small of a micro-optimization; at this scale the compiler writers are on nearly equal footing with the assembly hackers.  Maybe  if we had the bigger picture we could see a way to make it faster.

For example, you said that `-ffast-math` caused an undesirable loss of precision; this may indicate a numerical stability problem in the algorithm you are using.  With the right choice of algorithm, many problems can be solved with `float` instead of `double`.  (Of course, you may just need more than 24 bits.  I don't know.)

I suspect the `RCPSS` method shines if you want to compute several of these in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that pow function is very low, it's definitely on of the hotspots I'm removing from my code (when possible).
It seems that -mrecip doesn't any optimization (I just enabled -O3)

Comment: Have you profiled that? I did actually write a little tester for Carmack's method comparing `pow(x, -0.5f)`, `1.0f/sqrt(x)` and Carmack's method, and the latter is always faster by quite a lot. With `-ffast-math`, the first two are equally fast, and without, `pow` is the slowest. (Using GCC 4.6.3, `-O3` and `-march=native`.)

Comment: Yes my code is profile through cachegrind and visualized with Kcachegrind. is there that I saw the hotspot, but I didn't already convert my double to float before applying -mrecip. the problem is that here using ffast-math my results are very inaccurate.

Comment: @linello: Sorry, I was talking to Dietrich Epp, the post's author.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm trying to say that Carmack's method, while **faster** than naive methods like `pow` and `1.0/sqrt(x)`, is (1) **slower** than using a reciprocal estimate opcode for a given level of accuracy and (2) less useful for computing `1.0/(x*x)` than `1.0/sqrt(x)`.

Comment: @linello: Sometimes, inaccurate results with `-ffast-math` indicate a problem with numerical sensitivity in your algorithm (are you computing a sum somewhere, for example?) which can be fixed, allowing you to use `-ffast-math` without the loss of precision.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Oh OK, I see. How do you use the reciprocal estimate, concretely?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Can you post some code and instructions that makes GCC emit those RCPSS instructions? I've tried several permutations of `sqrtf` and compiler options, but no luck.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I've also had no luck.  I'm looking at an inline assembly version.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can certainly try and work something out. Let me just give you some general ideas, you can fill in the details.

First, let's see why Carmack's root works:

We write *x* = *M* × 2<sup>*E*</sup> in the usual way. Now recall that the IEEE float stores the exponent offset by a bias: If *e* denoted the exponent field, we have e = Bias + *E* ≥ 0. Rearranging, we get *E* = e − Bias.

Now for the inverse square root: *x*<sup>−1/2</sup> = *M*<sup>-1/2</sup> × 2<sup>−*E*/2</sup>. The new exponent field is:

*e'* = Bias − *E*/2 = 3/2 Bias − e/2

With bit fiddling, we can get the value *e*/2 from *e* by shifting, and 3/2 Bias is just a constant.

Moreover, the mantissa *M* is stored as 1.0 + *x* with *x* < 1, and we can approximate *M*<sup>-1/2</sup> as 1 + x/2. Again, the fact that only *x* is stored in binary means that we get the division by two by simple bit shifting.

Now we look at *x*<sup>−2</sup>: this is equal to *M*<sup>−2</sup> × 2<sup>−2 *E*</sup>, and we are looking for an exponent field:

*e'* = Bias − 2 *E* = 3 Bias − 2 *e*

Again, 3 Bias is just a constant, and you can get 2 *e* from *e* by bitshifting. As for the mantissa, you can approximate (1 + x)<sup>−2</sup> by 1 − 2 *x*, and so the problem reduces to obtaining 2 *x* from *x*.

Note that Carmack's magic floating point fiddling doesn't actually compute the result right aaway: Rather, it produces a remarkably accurate *estimate*, which is used as the starting point for a traditional, iterative computation. But because the estimate is so good, you only need very few rounds of subsequent iteration to get an acceptable result.

Answer (score 1):

For your current program you have identified the hotspot - good. As an alternative to speeding up 1/d^2, you have the option of changing the program so that it does not compute 1/d^2 so often. Can you hoist it out of an inner loop? For how many different values of d do you compute 1/d^2? Could you pre-compute all the values you need and then look up the results? This is a bit cumbersome for 1/d^2, but if 1/d^2 is part of some larger chunk of code, it might be worthwhile applying this trick to that. You say that if you lower the precision, you don't get good enough answers. Is there any way you can rephrase the code, that might provide better behaviour? Numerical analysis is subtle enough that it might be worth trying a few things and seeing what happened.

Ideally, of course, you would find some optimised routine that draws on years of research - is there anything in lapack or linpack that you could link to?

Comment: Thank for your very clever answer, but unfortunately the 1/d^2 has to be computed and updated and updated inside the inner loop, so no further simple optimization can be done. The range of values d takes is then far too big to precompute in a simple way.